# CSS to keep middle image in 100% width slideshow always in center

Tags: css, slideshow

Im trying to achive a slideshow that looks like this

http://ge.tt/api/1/files/2AjKcVM/0/blob/x675?noinc=1

where the width is  100%, and keeps scrolling infinitely left or right, but always having an image in the center no matter the browser resolution. This is what ive got so far

http://fourcreeklandscape.com/index2.html

the slideshow images have a width of 800px, the left most image has a margin-left of -25%... which sorta looks like it works in a 1280px screen size.... but doesnt look like its suppose to when i resize the window.

Heres the slideshow code im using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //move he last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks to slide left he will be able to see the last item.
    $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last')); 


    //when user clicks the image for sliding right        
    $('#right_scroll img').click(function(){

        //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
        var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

        //calculae the new left indent of the unordered list
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;

        //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '
        $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

            //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
            $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first')); 

            //and get the left indent to the default -210px
            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});
        }); 
    });

    //when user clicks the image for sliding left
    $('#left_scroll img').click(function(){

        var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

        /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;

        $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    

        /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first list item */            
        $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last')); 

        /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -210px */
        $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});
        });


    });});
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this CSS on #carousel_ul

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -1200px;
```

Just make sure it goes left to right. The only problem is if someone has a monitor wider than maybe 2000px, they will get a bit on the left with no image, when the slideshow first starts - but I think that is very few people.

Comment: thanks, its close, but not it does this weird little jump when you first click left or right... after that it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: you need to remove the left:-210px from the js, too, this whole line::             $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-210px'});

Comment: seems to have stopped loading the new divs now that i removed it... i also tried replacing the -210 for %50 so it matches the css. no luck

Comment: are you sure it's not cached? that doesn't make any sense. can you remove the line, and let me know so i can have a look?

Comment: yeah sure, i was just messing around with some things, but take a look at it now, i just updated it without that line

Comment: heres a link to the original script if it helps... http://web.enavu.com/demos/carousel.html

Comment: ok, i think what you have to do is set these two lines as this: $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '50%'}); - and then for the line where it sets the "left_indent", that's the part that's causing the jump when you hit the button. for that, you have to calculate the window size, and do 50% - 400px (maybe 405px, see how it looks). i don't have time right now to write that for, but see how you go and i will come back later tonight and see how you went :)

Comment: okok, i lied, try: var left_indent = $(window).width() - item_width/2;

Comment: nope, still not working... looks like its pretty close though, the animation just a little jumpy still. I dont know if this is relevant, but in the original script, the divs are sized at 200 pixes, might that have something to do with the -210px? and thanks again for all your help. i really appreciate it

Comment: yeah, the 210 is their width+padding, because their slideshow moves exactly that much to the left/right. for you the left_indent needs to move in relation to the browser window width, not in relation to the width of the slideshow window. it'll just be a case of adjusting the left_indent until it matches. i can't think of what the maths is going to be off the top of my head, so have a play!

Comment: yeah ive been playing around with the numbers... the more i look at it the less i understand how this script works actually... mostly the animate part, i dont get why they both say left, when one should be left the other should be right... but anyhow, thanks for your help, ill report back if i figure it out

Comment: took a little bit of hacking away, and simplifying  the code, but i got it to work. check it out... http://fourcreeklandscape.com/index3.html. thanks again for everything

Comment: awesome work! hope you learned a bit about javascript in the process. if you have a sec, it would be nice if you gave me an answer and/or a plus for my rank here :)