# css positioning issue with jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a slight issue, keeping the content in my carousel in place when i increase my screen size beyond 1200px content pushes to the left hand side of the screen [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php)

I've nested the carousel in it's own wrapper and given it the following css properties

```
.carsousel-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}   

.carousel{
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
}
.carousel-bg{
    margin-top: -542px;
}

.left-side{
    margin: -487px 40px;
}

#shots-carousel{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 46px 13%;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1600px;
}
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue, i've come across it before, managed to fix it but don't no how i did it. Can someone kindly pin-point me where i'm going wrong so i can save time in future.

Comment: Can you link to your page, or make a jsfiddle with all the necessary code?

Comment: Actually... dupe of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102042/css-to-keep-middle-image-in-100-width-slideshow-always-in-center/12102198#12102198

Comment: not quite mate, that's something completely different

Comment: and there is a link to my page, where it says "click here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was challenging! Interesting styles you're using there. This fixes it:

Get rid of the clearfix class on carousel, and change position:absolute to position:relative

You'll need to do the same sort of thing on .rslides_tabs

Comment: Ha! I spent so much trying to fix i made a bigger mess of it

Comment: ok, so on .carousel, change position:absolute to position:relative - that fixes the main area. just the coloured bars aren't working now, so see if you can get that bit fixed :)

Comment: yes the coloured bars are a ball ache. it's slowing me down big time

Comment: they should be the same width and positioning as the main div, shouldn't they? you could try copying the style of the main div onto the bars and seeing if that works. or maybe even put them inside the main div at the top, rather than at the end of the page and then absolutely positioned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15926/discussion-between-newboy-and-zenkaty)